# How to display a column in list_display that contains a clickable link, but can be sorted?

Tags: django-admin

In my `admin.ModelAdmin` instance for a model, I added a `list_display` that references another model. I would like that column to contain an HTML link. I read that the standard solution would involve creating a function that returns a string, but that means that I would lose the ability to sort by this field. Is there any other way I could inject HTML to this column?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `admin_order_field` for django to be able to sort objects based on the callable.

```
def some_callable(self, obj):
    return obj
some_callable.short_description = _("My Callable")
some_callable.admin_order_field = "foreignkey__id"
```

So if you create a function (callable) to display something for you (e.g. a link) and set the `admin_order_field`, check the last line of the sample code. (In my example it is id field of some foreign key, but you are free to use normal Django syntax to sort by `id`, `name`, or `pizza__ingridient__color`)